# Why isn't there a lombok plugin update for newer than 2021 Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I've seen that there is no update for a compatible Lombok Intellij plugin for an Intellij newer than 2021. I wonder if the reason for this was some update of Intellij to include this natively or any else reason such as no more maintenance?

I couldn't manage to find an announcement of anything on the subject.

The version history is in the [following link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/versions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JetBrains hired the original Lombok plug-in developer and bundled the plug-in with the IDE distribution. No additional plug-in installation is needed now.